# React testing-library - Testing a promise that set states in the first useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have a useEffect hook that loads when the component is mounted, as so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   listFiles().then(keys => {
      setKeys(keys)
      console.log(keys)
   }).catch(err => {
        showFail(err.message)
   })
}, [])
```

I'm trying to test the function with react testing-library, simply using the render function:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  render(<Dashboard />)
})
```

However, when I run any test that resolves the promise and sets the state:

```js
jest.mock('../utils/storage', () => ({
    listFiles: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([])),
}))
```

I end up with a weird warning message about using `act` to to wrap the event:

```js
  Warning: An update to Dashboard inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at .. 
        in Dashboard

      18 |     useEffect(() => {
      19 |         listFiles().then(keys => {
    > 20 |             setKeys(keys)
         |             ^
      21 |             console.log(keys)
      22 |         }).catch(err => {
      23 |             showFail(err.message)
```

I have tried wrapping the render in an `act`, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here? Should I be rendering in some other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error usually happens when you try to assert before the component has finished updating all state.

Note that inside `listFiles` you are calling `setKeys(keys)` and that updates the state.

You should `await` for the new keys(or files) to show up in the document:

```js
expect(await findByText('some file name or key')).toBeInTheDocument();
// more asserts here
```

Alternatively, you can [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) the mock to have been called (although I think the option above is better).

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(listFilesMock).toHaveBeenCalled());
// more asserts here
```

The methods above should already be wrapped in `act` for you by the React Testing Library, so you don't need to do it

---

#### What is `act()` from the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act):

> When writing UI tests, tasks like rendering, user events, or data fetching can be considered as “units” of interaction with a user interface. React provides a helper called act() that makes sure all updates related to these “units” have been processed and applied to the DOM before you make any assertions.
>
> The name act comes from the Arrange-Act-Assert pattern.

---

#### Useful links:

- [Fix act warning by React Testing Library author](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning)
- [React Act docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasn't mocking the useEffect async function.

component.test.tsx:

```
test('Working useEffect hook', () => {
  const dbCallMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
  render(<Tracks dbCallMock ={dbCallMock} />)
}
```

component.tsx:

```
export const myComponent = (props: {
  dbCallMock: Function
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<string[]>([])

  const getDbState= () => 
    db.state.toArray().then(gotState => setState(gotState))

  useEffect(
    () => (props.dbCallMock ? props.dbCallMock() : getDbState()),
    []
  )
}
```